# Javascript how to use a parameter in setTimeout callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display messages, and then hide them using the `setTimeout` function. So I would like the function I pass to the `setTimeout` function to take a parameter, the message to hide, so I can use 1 generic callback function. I tried the below code, but the `label` parameter is undefined when the callback executes.

```
var label = $('.js-a-label');
label.html('the message!');
setTimeout(hideMessage(label), 5000);

function hideMessage(label) {
  label.html('');
}
```

Comment: below sample would help

     function consoleIt(param){
     console.log(param);
     }

     setTimeout(function(){  
          consoleIt("hello")
       },3000);

Answer (score 1):

In *that* code, you can just use `label`, as your function closes over it:

```
var label = $('.js-a-label');
label.html('the message!');
setTimeout(hideMessage, 5000);
function hideMessage() {
  label.html('');
}
```

In the general case where the function you're calling *doesn't* close over the information you want it to use, you have a couple of options:

1. Add a function that does:

   ```
   var label = $('.js-a-label');
   label.html('the message!');
   setTimeout(function() { hideMessage(label); }, 5000);
   ```
2. Use [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (ES5+)

   ```
   var label = $('.js-a-label');
   label.html('the message!');
   setTimeout(hideMessage.bind(null, label), 5000);
   ```

   `Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, calls the original with a specific `this` value (we don't need that, so I just used `null` above) and any arguments you give `bind`.
3. Use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy), which does much the same thing as `Function#bind`:

   ```
   var label = $('.js-a-label');
   label.html('the message!');
   setTimeout($.proxy(hideMessage, null, label), 5000);
   ```